# Change paypal shopping cart/checkout input labels, form name and remove quantity input

Tags: php, paypal

how can I change the labels to the shopping cart? 
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart

Getting to this page by sending this form

```
<div class="paypal_module">

        <form id="paypal_form_1_buy_now_button" method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
            <div class="hiddenFields">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="nancy@somesite.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{homepage}advance-reservations/confirmation">
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="{homepage}">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="first_name" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="last_name" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="night_phone_a" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="city" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="zip" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="state" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="address1" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="address2" VALUE="">
                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="undefined_quantity" VALUE="1">
            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="trip-booking-submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="paypal_button button-sm-primary" style="float: right">
        </form>
```

I would need to change the labels as in this pic. Is this possible?

Changes needed:

- Change the form name from "Purchase details" to "Deposit details"
- Change input label from "Price per item" to "Deposit amount"
- Remove the quantity input

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Helping links: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/#setting-the-paypal-checkout-page-style

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: aww ... customer i'm working with needs the exact same thing as you

Comment: No you can't ! Use any other alternative option.

Comment: PayPal doesn't offer that level of customization unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you can customize certain sections of that page such as the header and logo, but you won't be able to customize it as much as you'd like.

Checkout [Paypal's docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/checkout-settings/) for information on customizing the above.

> When your account is created, PayPal sets up the default PayPal payment page style in your account profile. This default page style has PayPal branding only. Depending on your account type, your business name or email address appears in the upper left of the default page.
>
> Add your own custom payment page styles to co-brand the PayPal checkout pages with your logo and colors. You can add the following co-branding features to your custom pages:
>
> - Header image — Your own logo image, in place of your business name or email address.
> - Header background — A fill color of your choice, above the main page area.
> - Header border — A line color of your choice, above the main page area.
> - Background — A fill color of your choice, surrounding the main page area.